# GTK4 CSS does not apply in C language

Tags: css, c, gtk

I'm using GTK4 in C to build a GUI. I'm also using the GTK Builder to describe the UI. Now I want to style the UI by using CSS. All files are in the same directory. I'm running the code on a Mac and installed GTK with homebrew.
My C code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>

static void print_hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
  g_print("Hello World\n");
}

static void quit_cb(GtkWindow *window) {
  gtk_window_close(window);
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
  GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "builder.ui", NULL);

  GObject *window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window");
  gtk_window_set_application(GTK_WINDOW(window), app);

  GObject *button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1");

  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_hello), NULL);

  button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button2");
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_hello), NULL);

  GtkCssProvider *cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_file (cssProvider, g_file_new_for_path ("style.css"));
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(gdk_display_get_default(), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

  gtk_widget_set_visible(GTK_WIDGET(window), TRUE);
  
  g_object_unref(builder);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  #ifdef GTK_SRCDIR
    g_chdir(GTK_SRCDIR);
  #endif

  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

  int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}
```

CSS code:

```
GtkButton {
  background-color: red;
}
```

UI code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object id="window" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="title">Grid</property>
    <child>
      <object id="grid" class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="hexpand">TRUE</property>
        <property name="vexpand">TRUE</property>
        <child>
          <object id="button1" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 1</property>
            <property name="hexpand">TRUE</property>
            <property name="vexpand">TRUE</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="row">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object id="button2" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 2</property>
            <property name="hexpand">TRUE</property>
            <property name="vexpand">TRUE</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">1</property>
              <property name="row">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I want the buttons to have a red color but they have the default styling.

Answer (score 0):

"GtkButton" is not a valid css node, the css node for Gtk.Button is just called "button", ".image-button" and ".text-button", also applicable depending on the type of button. But if you don't want to use any of these, but your "GtkButton" class, you will have to add a new css class to the button with:

```
gtk_widget_add_css_class (
   GtkWidget* button,
   const char* "GtkButton"
)
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem, the css still does not apply.

Comment: Did you put the dot before the class name on css? ".GtkButton { background-color: red;}"

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
button.text-button {
        background: red;
}
```

in the CSS-code